# why regex match letter s in CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B unicode 20000-2A6DF?

Tags: regex, unicode, cjk

based on this example [What's the complete range for Chinese characters in Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode)

does the letter "s" belog to this alphabet?

```
var r = /[\u20000-\u2A6DF]/;
var t = 'sad';
console.log(t.match(r))
```

outpus `["s"]`

Why?

Comment: In JS, you can only use `\u`+4-symbol sequence to match code points.

Comment: CJK it is a commonly used acronym for "Chinese, Japanese, and Korean"

Comment: so why on unicode.org it says that: CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B Range: 20000–2A6D6

Comment: It is correct. Does this [*Javascript unicode string, chinese character but no punctuation*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109011/javascript-unicode-string-chinese-character-but-no-punctuation) post help you resolve your issue?

Comment: I think this is the solution. let me check.

Comment: These code points are outside of [*Basic Multilingual Plane*](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode). They cannot be handled in current JS implementation.

Comment: It helped me. That was the right answer! I didn't know that it shouldn`t be more than 4 characters after \u. TY!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87993/discussion-between-gigi-ionel-and-stribizhev).

Comment: it has common solution but not the same answer. If you see my question is why s is matched in that range, so the answer is because js does not support that range...how can you see this thing as duplicate? man...come on

Comment: I posted the answer, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you have contains [astral code points](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode):

> Astral code points are pretty easy to recognize: if you need more than 4 hexadecimal digits to represent the code point, it’s an astral code point.

These code points are outside of *Basic Multilingual Plane* (BMP) that can be used in JavaScript regex (e.g. `\u00XD`). 
However, JavaScript regex engine does not support astral code points (with the current ECMAScript implementation, it is already present in ECMAScript6, see [*Unicode code point escapes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#String_literals)).

Thus, the problem arises when JavaScript regex engine tries to interpret the regex pattern: it "sees" `\u2000`, then `0`, then `-`, then `\u2A6D`, then `F` inside your character class. Then, the engine creates a range between `0` and `\u2A6D` (`⩭`), which is a very large amount of characters, actually, and all English letters, and a lot more can be matched with this regex.

In the [Javascript unicode string, chinese character but no punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109011/javascript-unicode-string-chinese-character-but-no-punctuation) post, you can find a comprehensive Chinese character regex for JavaScript that consists of possible Unicode code point combinations used in Chinese, but there are a couple of typos in it.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var r = /(?:[\u4E00-\u9FCC\u3400-\u4DB5\uFA0E\uFA0F\uFA11\uFA13\uFA14\uFA1F\uFA21\uFA23\uFA24\uFA27-\uFA29]|[\ud840-\ud868][\udc00-\udfff]|\ud869[\udc00-\uded6\udf00-\udfff]|[\ud86a-\ud86c][\udc00-\udfff]|\ud86d[\udc00-\udf34\udf40-\udfff]|\ud86e[\udc00-\udc1d])+/g;
var t = '我的中文不好。我是意大利人。你知道吗？';
console.log(t.match(r));
```

Comment: well that`s my answer :)

Comment: Looks like it will be possible in the next generation of browsers supporting ECMAScript 6. See [ECMAScript 6 Compatibility Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Comment: In Google Chrome, you can actually use ECMAScript 6 syntax. 1) Go to `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony`  2) click *Enable*. However, I did not manage to make it use the astral code points with RegExp :(