# Javascript regular expression to allow unicode but disallow few special chars like *,[,],~ etc

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to allow unicode characters like chinese chars etc but don't want to allow special chars like *,[,],~ and also space, enter etc.

Comment: How do I ask a good question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript + Unicode regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [javascript-unicode-string-chinese-character-but-no-punctuation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109011/javascript-unicode-string-chinese-character-but-no-punctuation)

Comment: @YoucefLaidani note you can link to that page typing `[ask]`.

Comment: Thank you @fedoriqui this is a new information

Answer (score -1):

Metacharacter `\W` finds a non word character which includes all special characters.

```
var str = "{,[]&$pop^%$%%}";
var patt = /\W/g;
var string = str.replace(patt,"");
window.alert(string);
```

Comment: "\w or \W only matches ASCII based characters" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Regular_expression_and_Unicode_characters