# Event.preventDefault does not work when I input cjk(korean) on number type v-text-field

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on a vue project and this is a fix for little bug.
But it makes me so hard.

I made v-text-field is inputted only numbers and it seems to work good.

```
<v-text-field type="number">
```

And I want to input Only Number so I use keydown event for using preventDefault.

```
<v-text-field type="number" @keydown="testKeydown">
```

```
testKeydown(event) {
  if(event.key !== "1" && ... && event.key !== "Delete" && event.key !== "Backspace") {
    console.log("Wrong Input!!!");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

This code can prevent inputting exponential value 'e', 'E' and '+', '.'.

But it can not prevent Korean (maybe CJK) such as 'ㅁ'. (When I input Korean, event.key returns 'Process') And 'Wrong Input!!!' is logged my Chrome console.

Also, the value of v-text-field shown on the screen is '123ㅁ', but the value of event.target.value taken with console.log(event) is ' '.

I want to prevent Korean characters (or CJK) from being input or to erase them immediately even if they are entered without removing 'type="number"'.

What can I do for it?

Comment: I believe in this case you can create a regex and use the unicodes to filter them. http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop
This can help as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109011/javascript-unicode-string-chinese-character-but-no-punctuation

Comment: I think My question could make someone misunderstood. I will edit my question.
My probelm is that the value in the ```if()``` is not filtered, but the desired action is not performed properly when preventDefault() is executed.

Comment: Kanji (but also other Asian characters) requires several keypress-es in order to input a single Kanji symbol - if you are filtering the keypress-es you are breaking the IME (Input-method editor). You should remove the `@keydown` handler and instead put a watcher on your `v-model` - so you can react only after the Kanji symbol is fully entered but not before that.

Comment: I finally solved my problem. I set listeners and two of them do important work. CompositionStartListener execute ```this.$emit('input', '');``` and InputListener execute ```this.$emit('input', Number(this.preValue));```
When I let InputListener execute ```this.$emit('input', ''); this.$emit('input', Number(this.preValue));``` It does not work what I want
If here is someone who has similar problem, I hope to you solve them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called composition, it happens on certain IME when you need to type multiple strokes before composing a single character.

There are [`compositionstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/compositionstart_event) and [`compositionupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/compositionupdate_event) events which will fire in such cases, so you **should** have been able to handle these directly there and cancel them... Except that no browser supports cancelling these events yet...

So you have no choice but to wait for this composition to end, and to remove the bad inputs afterward. And the best for this is probably to listen for the `input` event. (Ps: you may anyway prefer to check for the input's value instead of testing all `event.key`, at least to catch pasted content.)

Comment: thank for your answer. I knew about composition event first. So I search it and I get result what it is impossible to prevent input Korean in my v-text-view. (or It can be solved but I'm cannot) I will research to solve my problem by other ways. Thank you.