# Uncompress a String, repeat chars `n` times

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have the following problem statement:

> Write a function, uncompress, that takes in a string as an argument.
> The input string will be formatted into multiple groups according to
> the following pattern:
>
> number + char
>
> for example, '2c' or '3a'.
>
> The function should return an uncompressed version of the string where
> each 'char' of a group is repeated 'number' times consecutively. You
> may assume that the input string is well-formed according to the
> previously mentioned pattern.
>
> test_00: uncompress("2c3a1t"); // -> 'ccaaat'

Here is my code which is using a stack. The problem is that it's only returning 'cc' and I can't figure out why. I've console logged what goes into the IF ELSE and I'm hitting both so I don't understand why nothing gets pushed to the stack.

Would really appreciate the help if someone can spot what I'm missing.

```js
const uncompress = (s) => { 
  const nums = '23456789';
  const stack = []; 
  for (let char of s) {
    if (nums.includes(char)) {
      stack.push(Number(char));
    } else {
      const num = stack.pop();
      stack.push(char.repeat(num));
    };
  };
  return stack.join('');
};

console.log(uncompress("2c3a1t")); // -> 'ccaaat'
```

Comment: I've added a snippet; it would be helpful if you could add examples showing inputs and expected outputs, along with what your function outputs. E.g., `console.log(uncompress('2c3a1t')); //  'ccaaat'`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I just amended the question.

Comment: Your code should be fine, you're just missing `1` in your `nums`;

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

Split the string up into pairs of numbers and chars:

```
str.match(/\d+[a-zA-Z]/g)
```

And reduce that array to a string, while taking each value from the array, getting the char from it (`cv.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)[0]`) and repeating it according to the number (`.repeat(parseInt(cv))`)

```js
const uncompress = str => str.match(/\d+[a-zA-Z]/g).reduce((acc, cv) =>
  acc + cv.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)[0].repeat(parseInt(cv)), "")

console.log(uncompress("2c3a1t"))
console.log(uncompress("27b1d8g"))
```

Comment: I love regex answers.  Is there anything regex can't solve?

Comment: @Trevor X/HTML is a big one, well, and other problems that deal with non-regular languages :P (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6634591)

Comment: What happens when you need to regex a non Latin based language?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109011/javascript-unicode-string-chinese-character-but-no-punctuation

Comment: That makes my eyes water.  You regex experts are a cut above.

Answer (score 0):

And just like that I was able to write the code which passed the test case:

```
  const nums = '123456789';
  const stack = []; 
  for (let char of s) { 
    if (nums.includes(char)) {
      stack.push(Number(char));
    } else {
      let num = '';
      while (nums.includes(stack[stack.length - 1])) {
        num += stack.pop(); 
      }
      stack.push(char.repeat(num));
    };
  };
  return stack.join('');
};
```