# Match css custom properties with Regxr

Tags: javascript, css, regex, css-variables, custom-properties

I want to match CSS custom properties with the Regxr pattern. 
So I tried with `/^(\*?[-#\/\*\\\w]+(\[[0-9a-z_-]+\])?)\s*/gim` which works fine with normal characters, but when it comes to emoji or other language characters, it doesn't work as expected.

```
--monster-x: purple;
--monster--x: red;
--monster-仮-x: blue;
```

Example:

[image]

How can I match all possible/supported CSS custom properties? Is there any doc for allowed/disallowed characters in CSS custom properties?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure thinks like emoji's are allowed in custom CSS propss?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in Chrome @0stone0

Comment: Ah, I hope the spec allows it. Would a regex that matches everything between `--` and `: ` be enough?

Comment: there could be invalid characters between `--` and `:`; Also, I will need to match normal properties as well, such as `background: red` @0stone0

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to expand your character list (`[]`) using the following:

###### Emoji's

[JavaScript regular expression for Unicode emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242440/javascript-regular-expression-for-unicode-emoji)

```
[\u{1f300}-\u{1f5ff}\u{1f900}-\u{1f9ff}\u{1f600}-\u{1f64f}\u{1f680}-\u{1f6ff}\u{2600}-\u{26ff}\u{2700}-\u{27bf}\u{1f1e6}-\u{1f1ff}\u{1f191}-\u{1f251}\u{1f004}\u{1f0cf}\u{1f170}-\u{1f171}\u{1f17e}-\u{1f17f}\u{1f18e}\u{3030}\u{2b50}\u{2b55}\u{2934}-\u{2935}\u{2b05}-\u{2b07}\u{2b1b}-\u{2b1c}\u{3297}\u{3299}\u{303d}\u{00a9}\u{00ae}\u{2122}\u{23f3}\u{24c2}\u{23e9}-\u{23ef}\u{25b6}\u{23f8}-\u{23fa}]
```

###### Chinese characters

[Javascript unicode string, chinese character but no punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109011/javascript-unicode-string-chinese-character-but-no-punctuation)

```
[\u4E00-\u9FCC]
```

---

Combining those char lists with your existing one will give us the following regex:

```
^(\*?[-#\/\*\\\w\u{1f300}-\u{1f5ff}\u{1f900}-\u{1f9ff}\u{1f600}-\u{1f64f}\u{1f680}-\u{1f6ff}\u{2600}-\u{26ff}\u{2700}-\u{27bf}\u{1f1e6}-\u{1f1ff}\u{1f191}-\u{1f251}\u{1f004}\u{1f0cf}\u{1f170}-\u{1f171}\u{1f17e}-\u{1f17f}\u{1f18e}\u{3030}\u{2b50}\u{2b55}\u{2934}-\u{2935}\u{2b05}-\u{2b07}\u{2b1b}-\u{2b1c}\u{3297}\u{3299}\u{303d}\u{00a9}\u{00ae}\u{2122}\u{23f3}\u{24c2}\u{23e9}-\u{23ef}\u{25b6}\u{23f8}-\u{23fa}\u4E00-\u9FCC]+(\[[0-9a-z_-]+\])?)\s*
```

##### > [Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VFQAEc/1)

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution, I think here the catch is, the pattern is going to get really long if I need to support other languages too.