# Error: Failed to recognize value `Han` for property `Script`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, regex, next.js

I am trying to filter Chinese characters from a string.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61151122/6880256), I can do:

```js
const nonChinese = /[^\p{Script=Han}]/gimu;
const text = "asdP asfasf这些年asfagg 我开源的 几个小项目sad asd";
console.log(text.replace(nonChinese, ""));
```

Expected output:

```
"这些年我开源的几个小项目"
```

This works in an online compiler like js fiddle: [js fiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/7rg4cq58/), but it does not work on my NextJs (with typscript) application and it gives me an compile error:

```
Error: Failed to recognize value `Han` for property `Script`.
```

This error is raised from:

```
index.js?46cb:365 Uncaught     at getUnicodePropertyValueSet (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel-packages\packages-bundle.js:315:46438)
    at getUnicodePropertyEscapeSet (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel-packages\packages-bundle.js:315:46885)
    at processCharacterClass (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel-packages\packages-bundle.js:315:47864)
    at processTerm (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel-packages\packages-bundle.js:315:48494)
    at rewritePattern (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel-packages\packages-bundle.js:315:50577)
    at PluginPass.RegExpLiteral (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel-packages\packages-bundle.js:74:17966)
    at i (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel\bundle.js:1890:373015)
    at NodePath._call (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel\bundle.js:1890:292626)
    at NodePath.call (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel\bundle.js:1890:292450)
    at NodePath.visit (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel\bundle.js:1890:293401)
    at processResult (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:49593:19)
    at <unknown> (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:49695:5)
    at <unknown> (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:140993:11)
    at <unknown> (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:140845:18)
    at context.callback (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:140718:13)
    at <unknown> (file://D:\code\personal-website\node_modules\next\dist\build\babel\loader\index.js:33:61)
```

May I know why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure why but after I changed the regex to:

```
const nonChinese = /[\P{Script=Han}]/gim
```

It just worked, if anyone is still facing the problem and you have only ASCII and Chinese characters, you can use an alternative that filters out all ASCII characters instead.

```
const allAscii = /[\x00-\x7F]/gim
```